# if $\gamma=\omega^\alpha$ for some ordinal $\alpha$, then $\gamma$ is indecomposable (explanation)

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I am reading the following proof, it shows that if $\gamma=\omega^\alpha$ for some ordinal $\alpha$, then $\gamma$ is indecomposable (e.i. $\beta_1+\beta_2<\gamma$ with $\beta_1, \beta_2<\gamma$):

> Let $\beta_1, \beta_2<\gamma=\omega^\alpha$. there exist $\alpha^{\prime}<\alpha$ and $n<\omega$ such that $\beta_1, \beta_2<\omega^{\alpha^{\prime}} \cdot n$; consider Cantor's normal forms of $\beta_1, \beta_2$. Hence $\beta_1+\beta_2<\omega^{\alpha^{\prime}} \cdot(k+k)<\omega^\alpha=\gamma$

I don't understand why:

1. > there exist $\alpha^{\prime}<\alpha$
2. > $\beta_1, \beta_2<\omega^{\alpha^{\prime}} \cdot n$
3. > $\beta_1+\beta_2<\omega^{\alpha^{\prime}} \cdot(k+k)$

could someone please clarify these questions for me?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. As it stands, your question is likely to be closed as too isolated.

On the topic of your question, have you written Cantor's normal forms for $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2,$ yet? Can you show what you've done with/learned from those forms?

Comment: @CameronBuie thanks. Yes, for the third question, I wrote $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ in Cantor's normal form but I still didn't figure out how to get to question 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For questions 1 & 2: Recall that $$\omega^\alpha = \begin{cases}
\lim_{n<\omega} \omega^{\alpha'}\cdot n &\text{ if } \alpha = {\alpha'}+ 1 \\
\lim_{{\alpha'}<\alpha} \omega^{\alpha'}&\text{ if } \alpha \text{ is a limit}
\end{cases}$$

Now, $\beta < \omega^\alpha$ implies $\beta$ is smaller than one of the elements in the limit; in both cases, it has the form $\omega^{\alpha'}\cdot n$.

For questions 3: I suspect it should have been $\beta_1+\beta_2< \omega^{\alpha^{\prime}} \cdot n + \omega^{\alpha^{\prime}} \cdot n=\omega^{\alpha^{\prime}} \cdot(n+n)<\omega^\alpha=\gamma$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.